# Creating a dynamic object literal collection with friendly keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create, from dynamic built form input, a collection of object literals with key value pairs that match the form's input names and values as the "key-value" pairs.

The following BuildDataCollection method code does create the collection, however it does not set the keys correctly. It assigns the iterator number instead of the expected key.

```
var PAS = {
    ReportData: {},        
    SubmitReport: function (ReportName) {
        //debugger
        this.BuildDataArray();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Monitor/_PAS_Report?ReportName=" + ReportName,
            data: this.ReportData,
        })
        .success(function (result) {                
           //get ajax response and display 
           $('#RprtContainer').html(result);
           $('#RprtContainer').show();
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) {
            console.error(status);
        })

    },
    BuildDataCollection: function () {
        debugger
        obj = document.getElementById("PASParameterForm");
        arr_Input = obj.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var arIName ="", arIVal ="";
        for (i = 0; i < arr_Input.length; i++) {
            arIName = arr_Input[i].name;
            arIVal = arr_Input[i].value;
            this.ReportData[i] = { arIName:arIVal };
        }

    }

}
```

How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: It should be `this.ReportData[arIName] = arIVal;`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple and very obvious once I spotted it:

```
this.ReportData[i] = { arIName:arIval };
```

to

```
this.ReportData[arIName] = arIVal ;
```

Comment: Adam's answer should be marked as correct because it explains the problem well